# Textexpander with Python to match phone numbers

Tags: python, clipboard, phone-number, textexpander

I want to use Textexpander and Python to match phone numbers via the clipboard:

1. Click a phone number formated like `0798008080` in one application, *copy* the number and insert the clipboard content with a Textexpander-Shortcut in another application like `0041 79 800 80 80`.
2. Click a phone number formatted like `079 800 80 80` in one application, *copy*, insert the clipboard content with a Textexpander-Shortcut in another application like `0041 79 800 80 80`.

I have found a Textexpander snippet which sets the clipboard content in uppercase:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
selection = """%clipboard"""
sys.stdout.write(selection.upper(),
```

but I have no clue how to adapt this snippet for my purpose (`%clipboard` is a code used in Textexpander to access the clipboard content)

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: How would you know if you have a telephone number on the clipboard?

Comment: will a python code with not Textexpander but clipboard package work for you ???

Comment: @RickyA: click on a phone number -> ⌘-C... or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @VikashSingh: Better not, because I work a lot with Textexpander, and a workflow with Textexpander would be more useful for me.

Comment: @NiWy: Please rephrase your question to convey that you need help in matching a pattern and transforming it to something else.

Comment: @hackworks: Yes I need still help in matching a pattern and transforming it.

Answer (score 0):

@hackworks:

Yes I need still help in matching a pattern and transforming it.

I suppose that I need a Python-, Ruby- or perhaps AppleScript-Code for transforming phone numbers like `0798008080` from the Clipboard (simple copy the number by  ⌘-C on a Mac) to `0041 79 800 80 80` and `079 800 80 80` to `0041 79 800 80 80`:

1. ⌘-C (copy) a phone number (`0798008080`) to the clipboard
2. Go to another application, we say Evernote/Word etc.
3. Tipping a defined abbreviation from Textexpander like `;phone` which paste the transformed phone number `0041 79 800 80 80` into Evernote/Word etc.

The Python-, Ruby- or AppleScript-Code transforming the phone number is within the snippet `;phone` from Textexpander:

1. If I type the shortcut `;phone` (or whatsoever: the shortcuts can be defined by the user itself), Textexpander should get the content from the clipboard (for that, the code `%clipboard` can be used within Textexpander),
2. then initiate a
3. Python-, Ruby- or whatsoever-code transforming the clipboard content (here: phone number),
4. transfer the transformed clipboard content to Textexpander,
5. which will (e) replace the shortcut `;phone` (Textexpander) with the transformed phone number and will insert the transformed phone number in Evernote/Word/Excel whatsoever

1, 2, 4 and 5 will be done by Textexpander. The clipboard content "transforming" Code will be also placed directly in the Textexpander snippet, in other words, Textexpander will initiate the Python-/Ruby-code.

In the example

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
selection = """%clipboard"""
sys.stdout.write(selection.upper(),
```

Textexpander will do like a similar process: This code is written within a Textexpander snippet. A shortcut like `;uc` (for uppercase) tipped in Word will start the Textexpander snippet. Textexpander will get the clipboard content (%clipboard), push a Python code (`sys.stdout.write(selection.upper(),`) to uppercase the clipboard content, and insert the transformed clipboard content in to Word. `#!/usr/bin/python`, `import sys` and `selection` also have something to do with Python (I suggest so), but I'am far away from really understand Python.

So, what I need is a Python/Ruby-code for transforming phone numbers formatted like `0798008080` and `079 800 80 80` to `0041 79 800 80 80` and to put in the code within Textexpander-workflow.

Does it make sense? Are my remarks understandable enough?

Answer (score 0):

After testing a while, I have found a solution with Regex. The following Regex match and transform the first example, `07966655522` to `0041 79 666 55 22`. I have to change this code, so that the example two (`079 600 80 80` to `0041 79 600 80 80`) will also matched with this one code, but this will take some time (any suggestions are welcome :-)):

Matching

```
^(0|[1-9])([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})
```

Transforming

```
0041 $2 $3 $4 $5
```